# MATLAB: Filtering out part of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of some deer behind a fence and I'm trying to remove the fence so that we can look straight at the deer without a fence in the way. So far I've, to a decent quality, segmented off (determined the coordinates of) the fence and am trying to replace the colors of these coordinates with nearby colors to simulate removing the fence.

Is there some image processing function in MATLAB that can help me easily accomplish my goal? I have tried the below code in which I try to find the nearest coordinate that isn't part of the fence, but "~ismember([i_temp,j],[ii,jj])" doesn't work because I'm trying to compare coordinates, but instead it seems to be comparing i_temp and j as separate variables, i.e. is i_temp not in ii or jj and is j in ii or jj.

```
%% 5. Locate pixel locations of the segmented image
% Now that the fence has been segmented. Locate the pixel locations of the
% segmented image

[ii,jj] = find(Img_threshold2==1);

n = length(ii); % Get a count of the number of coordinates

Rout = Rin;
Gout = Gin;
Bout = Bin;

%% 6. Recolor the areas of the fence with the nearest color available
for k=1:n
    i = ii(k);
    j = jj(k);

    keepLooping = true;
    i_add = 0;
    j_add = 0;
    i_coord = 0;
    j_coord = 0;

    % Find the nearest coordinate that is not a part of the fence
    while keepLooping
        i_add = i_add + 1;
        j_add = j_add + 1;

        % Check right
        i_temp = i + i_add;
        if ~ismember([i_temp,j],[ii,jj])
            i_coord = i_temp;
            j_coord = j;
            break
        end

        % Check left
        i_temp = i - i_add;
         if ~ismember([i_temp,j],[ii,jj])
            i_coord = i_temp;
            j_coord = j;
            break
         end

         % I would do check up and down, but the left/right doesn't even work
         % since ismember doesn't work as I expected
    end

    % Replace the color of the fence coordinate to the nearest non-fence
    % coordinate determined above
    Rout(i,j) = Rin(i_coord,j_coord);
    Gout(i,j) = Rin(i_coord,j_coord);
    Bout(i,j) = Rin(i_coord,j_coord);
end
```

EDIT 9/20/14:
Tried bwdist with the below code, where Iin is the input image and image_threshold2 is the segmented fence. Rather than getting the nearest color, the fence turned turquoise, which makes no sense since there is no turquoise in the image. Here is a screenshot demonstrating what happened. I cropped the image so I can test on a small area of the image, the actual image is much larger and has the actual deer and whatnot. Screenshot: http://gyazo.com/32ab37b8d2d9e137103d330a39d4ecfa

```
[D,IDX] = bwdist(~Img_threshold2);

% Replace the color of the fence coordinate to the nearest non-fence
% coordinate determined above
Iout = Iin;
Iout(Img_threshold2)=Iout(IDX(Img_threshold2));
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the image you're trying to process?

Comment: @Julio Revka, if the answer provided solved your problem please accept it at the left side of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a binary image where 1 is the fence and 0 the remain. Then use the [D,IDX] = bwdist(BW) function of Matlab. In IDX you have the closest non-fence index. Then you just have to assign to the voxel in the fence its closest non-fence value.

```
[D,IDX] = bwdist(~mask_fence) 
I(mask_fence)=I(IDX(mask_fence))
```

Comment: I tried this and rather than getting the nearest color of the fence, the fence turned turquoise, which is a color that exists nowhere in the image. See the edit I made in my original post.

Comment: If you are using 3 channels (RGB) then perform this over the 3 independent channels. Basically Ired(mask_fence)=Ired(IDX(mask_fence)),Igreen(mask_fence)=Igreen(IDX(mask_fence)),Iblue(mask_fence)=Iblue(IDX(mask_fence))

Comment: Yep, I just thought of that and implemented it. Then looked back here and saw my idea matched your suggestion :). Seems to be working thanks.